# how can i get mm/yy output while use of 'form.date_select :date' in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

hi i am take date as date data type in rails but i only want to show user date as mm/yyyy format. here is form code but when i execute this code using strftime('%m%y') i am getting error nil:class but without using strftime i am getting output as yyyy-mm-dd format. how can i get output as mm/yy format or month-year format

form.html.erb

```
<%= form_with(model: project_site, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if project_site.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(project_site.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this project_site from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% project_site.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

<div class="row">
    <div class="field medium-3 columns">
      <%= form.label :name %>
      <%= form.text_field :name %>
    </div>
<!--
    <div class="field medium-3 columns">
      <%= form.label :date %>
      <%= form.text_field :date, class: 'datepicker' %>
    </div>
-->
      <div class="field medium-3 columns">
        <%= form.label :upload_attendance %>
        <%= form.file_field :file %>
      </div>

      <div class="field medium-6 columns">
        <%= form.label :attendance_month %>
        <%= form.date_select :date, { :discard_day => true, :discard_month => false, :discard_year => false } %>
      </div>

    <div class="actions">
      <br>
      <%= form.submit 'Upload Attendance', :class => 'button primary'%>
    </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

show.html.erb

```
<%= project_site.date %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using [`strftime`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.5/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime)?

```
<%= project_site.date.strftime("%m%Y") %>
```

Comment: undefined method `strftime' for "{1=>2019, 2=>12, 3=>1}":String
Did you mean?  strip

Comment: That means `date` is not stored as a Date in the database but as a JSON String. Did you do that on purpose? If not then I recommend changing the column type to `date`.

Comment: hi after changing column type still getting error like undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Please copy and paste and the whole form, the log entries from an example create request and your controller methods into your question. It seems like Rails isn't storing the `date` into your database and therefore returns `nil`.